# How can I fix and make my code work in c++?

Tags: c++, set

> Create a program that gives you the teacher with the fewest hole hours.

> We know from a school’s teachers what class they are holding. The teachers,the subjects, the days of the week, the hours within the days with their serial numbers we identify.

> Input:
> The number of hours in the first line of the standard input (1=<O<1000) is the number of teachers (1=<N=<100), the number of subjects (1=<M=<100) is separated by a space.
> Each of the following lines contains 4 integers, one with a space
> separated: the serial number of the teacher (1=<TS=<N), the serial number of the taught subject (1=<TTS=<M), the day (1=<Day=<5) and the hour (0=<Hour=<8). For example 3 7 2 0 it means that the third teacher takes the seventh subject on the second day of the week he teaches in the zero hour.

> Output:
> A single line of standard output should contain the serial number of the teacher who has the fewest hole clocks (hole clocks: no clocks, but
> he has an hour sometime before that day and an hour sometime after that)! More in case of a solution, the smallest serial number must be printed!

My idea :
1.count how many hole hours a teacher has
2.we choose the one who has the least

My code is now the first one. How can I fix it?

```
Input 
8 3 4 
1 1 1 6
1 1 2 2
1 2 1 3
2 1 2 2
2 2 3 1
3 4 1 2
3 2 1 4
3 3 2 1

Output: 2
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
     int O;  // number of lessons
     int N;  //number of teachers
     int M;  // number of subjects

     cin >> O >> N >> M;

     int teachernumber [N];
     int lessonnumber [N];
     int day [N];
     int lesson [N];

     for (int i = 0; i <O; i ++)
     {
         cin >> teachernumber [i];
         cin >> lessonnumber [i];
         cin >> day [i];
         cin >> lesson [i];
     }

     set lessons [O];
     int pounchlessonDB [N];


     for (int i = 1; i <N; i ++) // Teachers
     {
           for (int j = 1; j <6; j ++) // Days (1-5)
           {
             lessons.clear ()

             for (int k = 0; k <9; k ++) // Hours (0-8)
             {
                 if ((i, j, k)! = 0)
                 {
                     orak.add (k)
                 }
             }

             if (orak.size ()> 1)
             {
                 pounchlessonDB + = lessons.end-lessons.begin-lessons.size
             }

           }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: VLA (Variable Length Array) is not part of the C++ standard. It is invalid code. Use ````std::vector```` instead. If I would understand, what you want to achieve, I could help you. Better post the link to the original question. Additionally. You create an array of sets (lessons), but you call ````lessons.clear```` without any index. That is a bug.

Comment: I post the original question.Do you think I can change Variable Length Array for a block?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your arrays to vectors (to make it valid C++) and renamed the variables to descriptive names.

Here you seem to assume that all vectors are the same size:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_lessons; i++) {
    std::cin >> teachernumber[i];
    std::cin >> lessonnumber[i];
    std::cin >> day[i];
    std::cin >> lesson[i];
}
```

This is clearly not the case as you read the first line:

```
8 3 4
```

using

```
std::cin >> num_lessons >> num_teachers >> num_subjects;
```

So, `num_lessons` is clearly greater than the size of your vectors (they're all `num_teachers`). This is never going to go well.

After fixing that, I find code that doesn't exist or cannot compiler:

```
if ((i, j, k) ! = 0) {
```

That's not ... useful code. What does it mean?

```
orak.add(k)
```

What is orak?

```
set lessons;
```

Did you mean std::set? In that case, what is the element type? Let's assume:

```
std::set<int> lessons;
```

Member functions must be invoked (well, usually): `lessons.begin` should be `lessons.begin()`.

Current draft:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> teachernumber;
    std::vector<int> lessonnumber;
    std::vector<int> day;
    std::vector<int> lesson;

    {
        int num_lessons;  // number of lessons
        int num_teachers; // number of teachers
        int num_subjects; // number of subjects

        std::cin >> num_lessons >> num_teachers >> num_subjects;

        teachernumber.resize(num_lessons);
        lessonnumber.resize(num_lessons);
        day.resize(num_lessons);
        lesson.resize(num_lessons);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < teachernumber.size(); i++) {
        std::cin >> teachernumber[i];
        std::cin >> lessonnumber[i];
        std::cin >> day[i];
        std::cin >> lesson[i];
    }

    std::set<int>    lessons;
    std::vector<int> pounchlessonDB(teachernumber.size());

    for (int i = 1; i < teachernumber.size(); i++) // Teachers
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) // Days (1-5)
        {
            lessons.clear();

            for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) // Hours (0-8)
            {
                if ((i, j, k) ! = 0) {
                    orak.add(k)
                }
            }

            if (orak.size() > 1) {
                pounchlessonDB += lessons.end() - lessons.begin() -
                    lessons.size()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Fixing

Whenever you have

```
    teachernumber.resize(num_lessons);
    lessonnumber.resize(num_lessons);
    day.resize(num_lessons);
    lesson.resize(num_lessons);
```

That clearly means you should be using

```
struct entry {
    int teacher;
    int subject;
    int day;
    int lesson;
};

int num_lessons, num_teachers, num_subjects; // number of subjects
std::cin >> num_lessons >> num_teachers >> num_subjects;

std::vector<entry> roster(num_lessons);
```

In fact, let's just dynamically read all the entries:

```
std::vector<entry> roster;
while (num_lessons--) {
    auto& added = roster.emplace_back();
    std::cin >> added.teacher >> added.subject >> added.day >> added.lesson;
}
```

In fact, let's use literate code and expressive names:

```
enum Day { Monday = 1, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday };
using TeacherId = unsigned;
using SubjectId = unsigned;
using Hour      = unsigned; // 0..8

struct Entry {
    TeacherId teacher;
    SubjectId subject;
    Day       day;
    Hour      timeslot;
};

unsigned num_lessons, num_teachers, num_subjects; // number of subjects
std::cin >> num_lessons >> num_teachers >> num_subjects;

std::vector<Entry> roster;
while (num_lessons--) {
    auto& added = roster.emplace_back();
    unsigned day;
    std::cin >> added.teacher >> added.subject >> day >> added.timeslot;
    added.day = static_cast<Day>(day);
}
```

> Input validation is left as an exercise for later

Now, to count "hole hours" you basically want rosters ordered by (teacher, day, hour) but disregarding the subject (because that is irrelevant). I'd change the container to a set and add the ordering:

```
std::set<Entry> roster;

while (num_lessons--) {
    Entry added;
    unsigned day;
    std::cin >> added.teacher >> added.subject >> day >> added.timeslot;
    added.day = static_cast<Day>(day);

    roster.insert(added);
}
```

With the ordering:

```
    bool operator<(Entry const& other) const
    {
        return std::tie(teacher, day, timeslot) <
            std::tie(other.teacher, other.day, other.timeslot);
    }
```

Encapsulating the logic in a class, you'd get something like:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19299d62abb3df6d)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

enum Day { Monday = 1, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday };
using TeacherId = unsigned;
using SubjectId = unsigned;
using Hour      = unsigned; // 0..8

struct Roster {
    struct Entry {
        TeacherId teacher;
        SubjectId subject;
        Day       day;
        Hour      timeslot;

        bool operator<(Entry const& other) const
        {
            return std::tie(teacher, day, timeslot) <
                std::tie(other.teacher, other.day, other.timeslot);
        }
    };

    std::set<Entry> _entries;

    void add(Entry entry) {
        auto [it, no_conflict] = _entries.insert(std::move(entry));
        assert(no_conflict);
    }

    auto daySchedule(TeacherId t, Day d) const
    {
        return std::pair(_entries.lower_bound({t, 0, d, 0}),
                         _entries.upper_bound({t, 0, d, 8}));
    }

    auto allTeachers() const
    {
        std::set<TeacherId> result;
        for (auto& e : _entries)
            result.insert(e.teacher);
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Roster roster;

    unsigned num_scheduled_lessons, num_teachers, num_subjects; // number of subjects
    std::cin >> num_scheduled_lessons >> num_teachers >> num_subjects;

    while (num_scheduled_lessons--) {
        Roster::Entry lesson;
        unsigned      day;
        std::cin >> lesson.teacher >> lesson.subject >> day >> lesson.timeslot;
        lesson.day = static_cast<Day>(day);

        roster.add(lesson);
    }

    //for (auto& [t,s,d,h]: roster._entries) {
        //std::cout << t << " " << s << " " << d << " " << h << "\n";
    //}

    TeacherId winner = -1;
    unsigned  least_holes = 5 * 8; // start with max

    for (auto teacher : roster.allTeachers()) {
        unsigned holes = 0;
        for (int day = Monday; day <= Friday; ++day) {
            auto [begin, end] = roster.daySchedule(teacher, Day(day));

            if (begin == end) {
                // no lessons scheduled that day
            } else {
                unsigned first_hour  = begin->timeslot,
                         last_hour   = std::prev(end)->timeslot,
                         num_lessons = std::distance(begin, end);

                holes += (last_hour + 1 - first_hour) - num_lessons;
            }
        }

        if  (holes < least_holes) {
            winner = teacher;
            least_holes = holes;
        }
    }

    std::cout << winner << "\n";
}
```

Which prints

```
2
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not working and I do not understand it because I haven't learnet std:: yet.

Comment: No worries. The goal of (my) answers is not to do your homework for you. You can probably find your way using the information in the first paragraphs of my answer. Because that points out the biggest mistakes in your question code.